# How to use Facebook Graph API to get user posts from any open buying and selling groups on facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am trying to get user posts from buy and sell groups that are open (viewable) for a school project. I just need read access to the data. I am trying to use the search aspect of the graph API but it is redirecting me to making a request as it is not allowing me to view any public data.

**Tried the following: **

- I have tried submitting a request; It asked for tons of information, including my passport, driver's licence and other images. It said that it will take 2-3 business days but I am still not approved on day 7
- I have tried contacting facebook on their toll free number but it did not work out since they have no one monitoring the calls and they just redirect you a link
- I have tried submitting a request; Verification of my request also seem to be not working since I am stuck on stage of uploading my app-icon. Even though I keep on uploading the image that fits into the description, it is not letting me update the picture of the app-icon.

**Screenshots:**

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1hV28imkpyZLztHxYZNzIBa8t97Y3t3M8

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1TnvUegreUuYv7OmzWzbcJsYOffzzqDmI

Comment: Pretty sure there are no API to access buy/sell posts.

Comment: can I not use the groups API?

Comment: Sure you can. But I'm pretty sure it doesn't contain buy/sell posts